# .htaccess RewriteRule query isn't working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't get the following `RewriteRule` to work.

I have a PHP SQL query to display a web page. It requires a `RewriteRule` rule which I'm trying to achieve in a `.htaccess` file.

Here is the full URL at the moment.

```
www.example.com/category/sub-cat/page.php?art_url=a-page-of-mine
```

I can't get it to do

```
www.example.com/category/sub-cat/a-page-of-mine
```

My Code below:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /error-404.php
#error 404
RewriteRule    ^error/?$    error-404.php    [NC,L]
    RewriteRule    ^category/sub-cat/(0-9a-zA-Z]+) category/sub-cat/page.php?art_url=$1   [NC,L]
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Missing a few things here `(0-9a-zA-Z]+)` like `[-` as in `([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](//stackoverflow.com/q/9153262) (already voted to close as typo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right. To get this working I needed to add QSA as in [QSA,NC,L]. After how many weeks!!??

Answer (score 1):

AS I said in the comments

Missing a few things here `(0-9a-zA-Z]+)` like `[-` as in `([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)`

This is going to bite you too...

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Match everything that doesn't have a dot and add `.php` to it with the `[L]` last flag.  I would bet it will never pass that one in the first place.

Generally you want the more specific rules first, followed by the more generic ones last.

Also if I recall correctly the `NC` i no case, so you can get rid of the `A-Z` and just do `[-a-z0-9]+`

**A better way**

I try to avoid query string rewrites and rely on the URI method of rewriting common in MVC frameworks

```
  example.com/index.php/category/sub-cat/a-page-of-mine
```

And then use a router and HTACCESS to only remove the `index.php` it's much simpler that way.

I have a pretty bare bones router on my GitHub page that shows how to route URL's like that.

https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/tree/master/Router

One big issue with messing with the query string is you can lose the ability to use `$_GET` the way it's designed to be used for things like search forms etc.  So it's better to route not rewrite.  Also the MVC way gives you a single entry point for all requests to go through which can make it easier to manage things like Constants, and Autoloaders....

Comment: And `Options +MultiViews` is also going to "conflict" with the mod_rewrite directive that appends `.php`. In fact, in this case, it's mod_negotiation that appends the `.php`, not mod_rewrite (when the `.php` file exists). So, the later rewrites do still get processed, despite the earlier directive having an `L` flag -  because the earlier rewrite isn't successful. (Except when the `.php` file does not exist then the mod_rewrite directive _does_ append the `.php` extension, because mod_negotiation hasn't!)

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, this is broken of course:

```
(0-9a-zA-Z]+)
```

The charclass lacks the opening `[` and doesn't contain/match a literal `-` as well.